# Reload only particular controller for $state.go

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a nested routing in my single page application. So from state `client.forms.instance` I go to another $state as below,

```
 $state.go('client.forms.instance.rendering', { 'sectionId': sectionId });
```

This `client.forms.instance.rendering` is like this,

```
var forms = {
            url: '/sections/:sectionId',
            templateUrl: 'scripts/client/forms/formInstance/rendering/formRendering.html',
            controller: 'RenderingController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
        };
        $stateProvider.state('client.forms.instance.rendering', forms);
```

So when I `$stage.go` to `client.forms.instance.rendering` I want to reload controller `RenderingController`.

The URL change correctly. But `RenderingController` is not re initialize everytime.

Btw I add that `RenderingController` with the html to the main view as below.

```
<div ng-include="'scripts/client/forms/formInstance/rendering/formRendering.html'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$state.go('client.forms.instance.rendering',{'sectionId':sectionId},{reload:true});
```

---

To not reload the parent controller. I think instead of manually injecting the template within `ng-include`, you'll need to add this inside parent template (`instance`):

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

then within `'client.forms.instance.rendering'` **ui-router** should know that `rendering` is child of `instance` and will inject the appropriate template inside and render its related controller whenever the `url` is matching or its `state` is invoked.

In case if many states should be injected in the same page. then you may consider using named views. More details can be found here :

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: I have tried this. But from reload: true, the controller for client.forms.instance reload as well. I don't want that parent controller to reload

Comment: mmm I misunderstood your question. I think you need to to use `ui-view` instead of `ng-include`. `<div ui-view></div>` if ui-router knows that `instance` is parent of `rendering` then it will inject the related template inside. did you try that ?